# When I edit an event in Google Calendar, it gets cancelled in attendees calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Im using service account to authenticate.

async updateGoogleMeetData(
dto: UpdateEventDto,
): Promise {
await this.calender.events.get({
calendarId: 'primary',
eventId: dto.eventId,
});

```
const attendeesEmails = [dto.candidateEmail, dto.primaryPanelistEmail, dto.secondaryPanelistEmail, ...(dto.otherAttendeesEmail?.length > 0 ? dto.otherAttendeesEmail.map((email) => (email)) : [])]

try {
  //Adjust interview start and end times based on IST timezone
  const getConvertedTime = this.timeConversion.convertUtcToIst(
    dto.interviewStartDateTime,
  );

  // Define the updated event details
  const updatedEvent = {
    summary: dto.meetSubject,
    description: `This is regarding an interview scheduled for the position of ${dto.jobTitle.toUpperCase()} \nNote:Set-up your calender to IST format`,

    start: {
      dateTime: getConvertedTime.interviewStartTime.toISOString(),
      timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
    },

    end: {
      dateTime: getConvertedTime.interviewEndTime.toISOString(),
      timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
    },

    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        requestId: uuid(),
      },
    },

    attendees: attendeesEmails,

  };
  // Update the Google Calendar event with the new details
  await this.calender.events.update({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    eventId: dto.eventId,
    resource: updatedEvent,
    sendUpdates: 'all',
  })

  // Send a templated email to notify about the update
  //this.emailService.UpdateTemplatedEmail(dto);
  return { message: 'Google meet updated with provided changes' };
} catch (error) {
  if (error.status === 404) {
    throw new NotFoundException('Invalid Google Meet Id');
  }

  throw new InternalServerErrorException(
    'Internal Server Error: Failed to update google meet with provided changes',
  );
}
```

}

I used patch method instead of update but same problem